# Whats the best way to terminate a Parallel.ForEach loop from the local init lambda?

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

In my `Parallel.ForEach` loop i have some objects that I need to initialize in the "local init" lambda.
If one of these objects fails to initialize, I would like to terminate the entire parallel loop.
What is the best way to do this?

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection,
   () => //local init
   {
      var localObjects= CreateObjects();
      foreach (var obj in localObjects)
         if (!obj.Initialize())
            // want to terminate the entire parallel loop here!!
      return localObjects;
   }
   (element, loopState, localObjects) => // loop body
   {
      // some code here
   },
   localObjects => // local finally
   {
      foreach (var obj in localObjects)
         obj.Terminate();
   });
```

Comment: Just so we're sure, here - you are aware that the localInit and localFinally will be called once for *each* element in the `collection` collection, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this (with out seeing any code), would be to check if the object you attempted to initialise is `null`, if it is, `break()`.

I hope this helps.

*Edit. Following some comments, `stop()` might be the better option in this case.*

Comment: that would work, but i would like something cleaner. I thought about throwing an exception from there, which should do the trick I think

Comment: @dmg Please don't use exceptions to control application logic. They're for exceptional events, that you don't expect. By the code you've written, you seem to expect things to not initialise.

Comment: Definitely in this code initialization can fail fairly easily

Comment: @J.Steen is correct here. Don't use an exception. It may be ugly, but not every thing you do in development is a picture. This is a purely functional operation and I don't see that you have any other option...

Comment: Seeing your code, it has to be a break. Or event uglier, a `goto`. Wait I think FORTRANs at the door...

Comment: @dmg It's easy for me to preach the evil of using exceptions for application logic, but truth be told, sometimes you just have no other choice. If neither of our solutions are usable for you, and if you can bear the cost of exceptions in your code, by all means. Be pragmatic and do what you have to.

Comment: One does not simply `break` out of `Parallel.ForEach()`. That's  because it's not a loop, as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: I did mean break() here, this was an oversight... However, your suggestion to use `stop()` might indeed be the way to go in this case. Thanks again...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this.

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection,
   () => //local init
   {
      var localObjects= CreateObjects();
      foreach (var obj in localObjects)
         if (!obj.Initialize())
            return null; // returning null as a "flag" for the loop
                         // body block to use
      return localObjects;
   },
   (element, loopState, localObjects) => // loop body
   {
      if (state.IsStopped || localObjects == null)
      {
         // will signal to stop at earliest convenience
         loopState.Stop();

         // will make sure nothing is done this iteration
         return null;
      }

      // some code here
   },
   localObjects => // local finally
   {
      foreach (var obj in localObjects)
         obj.Terminate();
   });
```

Note that this will mean that localObjects in the finally block will be null as well, and nothing will be `Terminate()`d.

Comment: `Break()` stops *following iterations*, that's not what you want here, you want to stop everything. For that, use [`Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop.aspx).

Comment: @svick In all honesty, I was choosing between the two. However, I couldn't see a difference in my own tests with this code. It'll still finish iterations already spawned. Considering it needs to be coupled with `IsStopped`, I left it out. Modifying. =)

Comment: It will make a difference if only some of the local objects fail to initialize. (E.g. if the local object for items 75–100 doesn't initialize, using `Break()` means items 75–100 won't be processed, but items 0–74 *will*.)

Comment: That's just what `Break()` is meant to do, have a look at Remarks in [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break.aspx).

Comment: @svick I meant the edit, not your explanation. I understood it perfectly, thanks a lot for making that clear. =)

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. Yeah, I think this is the right way to do it.